# Dundered global variable cannot be accessed inside a class method

Tags: python, global

I am experiencing an obscure (to me) effect of dundered scoping, and trying to work out the rule for it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

stuff = "the things"
__MORE_STUFF = "even more"

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        global __MORE_STUFF # doesn't help
        print(stuff) # is OK
        print(__MORE_STUFF) # fail!

Thing()
```

results in

```
$ python3 dunder.py
the things
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dunder.py", line 12, in <module>
    Thing()
  File "dunder.py", line 10, in __init__
    print(__MORE_STUFF) # fail!
NameError: name '_Thing__MORE_STUFF' is not defined
```

What is supposed to be a module-global variable is being treated as a class-level property - which, being undefined, is flagged as being undefined.

I've been trying to look through the documentation for this, but I cannot seem to work out what the rule is.

Can anyone point me to the appropriate documentation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers

Comment: All such names in a class definition, not just attributes, are subject to name mangling. Don't use such class-private names at the module scope.

Comment: What do you mean with "dundered"?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OP is referring to names that begin (but do not end) with a double underscore. ("Dunder" usually refers to names that begin *and* end with double underscores, though.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I googled the term, but found nothing (other than suggestions that maybe I meant sundered).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers refers to them as "system-defined names", but acknowledges the informal term "dunder".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) refers to such names as *class-private* names:

> `__*`
>
> Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to
> help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and
> derived classes. See section [Identifiers (Names)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

Since subclassing isn't something that applies to modules (at least, not to the extent that the language provides any tools or recommendations regarding how you might go about it), there's no need to use class-private names where `_`-prefixed names will do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

stuff = "the things"
_MORE_STUFF = "even more"

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        print(stuff) # is OK
        print(_MORE_STUFF)

Thing()
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is a bit implicit that the same effect applies to module-level variables, didn't expect that.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that used; I'm not sure what the rationale is. I suspect it's easier, once the AST has been generated, to simply process all identifier nodes without having to identify attribute lookups?